# Virtual functions with differences here and there

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

Consider this output:

```
Current time: 6:30 pm
Current time: 18:30
Current time: evening.
Current time: evening (for many it is dinner time, but many eat dinner later).
```

Note that the last two have a period, while the first two do not.  I obtained this desired output with the `System::displayCurrentTime` member function from the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class TimeDisplay {
    public:
        virtual std::string tell() const = 0;
        virtual std::string tellMaybeWithPeriod() const = 0;
};

class ClockDisplay12Hours : public TimeDisplay {  // #1
    std::string tell() const override {return "6:30 pm";}
    std::string tellMaybeWithPeriod() const override {return tell();}
};

class ClockDisplay24Hours : public TimeDisplay {  // #2
    std::string tell() const override {return "18:30";}
    std::string tellMaybeWithPeriod() const override {return tell();}
};

class DescriptiveTimeDisplay : public TimeDisplay {  // #3
    std::string tell() const override {return "evening";}
    std::string tellMaybeWithPeriod() const override {return tell() + ".";}
};

class CrazyDescriptiveTimeDisplay : public TimeDisplay {  // #4
    std::string tell() const override {return "evening (for many it is dinner time, but many eat dinner later)";}
    std::string tellMaybeWithPeriod() const override {return tell() + ".";}
};

struct System {
    static std::shared_ptr<TimeDisplay> timeDisplay;
    static std::string timeAsString() {return timeDisplay->tell();}
    static std::string timeAsStringMaybeWithPeriod() {return timeDisplay->tellMaybeWithPeriod();}
    // #3 and #4 will have a period, the others will not.
    static void displayCurrentTime (std::shared_ptr<TimeDisplay> t) {
        timeDisplay = t;
        std::cout << "Current time: " << System::timeAsStringMaybeWithPeriod() << '\n';
    }
    static void foo (std::shared_ptr<TimeDisplay>) {}  // #1 and #3 will have a period, the others will not.
    static void bar (std::shared_ptr<TimeDisplay>) {}  // #1, #2, and #4 will have a period, the others will not.
    static void baz (std::shared_ptr<TimeDisplay>) {}  // #2 will have a period, the others will not
};
std::shared_ptr<TimeDisplay> System::timeDisplay;

int main() {
    const std::shared_ptr<TimeDisplay> clocks[] = {std::make_shared<ClockDisplay12Hours>(), std::make_shared<ClockDisplay24Hours>(),
        std::make_shared<DescriptiveTimeDisplay>(), std::make_shared<CrazyDescriptiveTimeDisplay>()};
    for (std::shared_ptr<TimeDisplay> t : clocks)
        System::displayCurrentTime(t);
}
```

This is not terribly messy, but not note that the next functions to implement `foo`, `bar`, `baz` want the periods with different derived classes of `TimeDisplay`, and there are actually much more than 4 such derived classes, and also more than 3 new member functions to take care of.  Is there a cleaner more elegant way to handle these upcoming member functions than to write out new virtual functions for each of `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, etc... along with which will get the period and which will not?  Use templates somehow (e.g. renaming the derived classes `Derived<0>`, `Derived<1>`, etc... and then using these compile-time integers to fit the rules stated in the comments above)?  Of maybe avoid templates and do something else?

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: How best to implement `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, etc... by following the rules stated in the comments above without repeating the mess that  `displayCurrentTime` is creating?  Otherwise, the number of new virtual functions will explode.  I left `foo`, `bar`, `baz` blank because it is only the period business that is to worry about.

Comment: What's wrong with using the following code:

`static void displayCurrentTime (std::shared_ptr<TimeDisplay> t) {
        std::cout << "Current time: " << t->tellMaybeWithPeriod() << '\n';
    }`

Comment: Because `tellMaybeWithPeriod()` only applies for #3 and #4 getting the period.  What about all the other cases stated above?

Comment: So there's 4 different display types which can be passed to any of 4 different functions, each of which have different rules for the presence of the trailing period. Yeah, that's obviously creating 4x4=16 possibilities... My first reaction isn't to try to solve this design, but rather go back to the actual requirements and see if there's a different way to dealing with this entirely. (For instance, a single function which takes two parameters: the display type and a bool of whether to have a period or not.)

Comment: Yes, I'm open to an entirely different approach, as long as `System` keeps its member `std::shared_ptr<TimeDisplay> timeDisplay;`, because this "Bridge design pattern" is what I'm using throughout my program.  My initial idea with templates is not working.  Passing more arguments is definitely an idea to consider.  And it is not 4x4.  More like 12x12 in my program.

Comment: How about making each class derive from the previous one, instead of all from the same base? Then you don't need to repeat functions that are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by giving a bool template parameter to the four clock display classes. e.g.

```
template <bool P>
class DescriptiveTimeDisplay : public TimeDisplay {  // #3
    std::string tell() const override { return "evening"; }
    std::string tellMaybeWithPeriod() const override { return tell() + (P ? "." : ""); }
};
```

and control whether the period will be displayed by intantiate the class as, e.g.

```
std::make_shared<DescriptiveTimeDisplay<true>>()
```

for each of the four functions `displayCurrentTime`, `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, you can control their display format by instantiating the four `TimeDisplay` child classes with different bool template parameters.

Comment: @ simon   Thank you very much.  I posted a full solution based on your idea.  Template meta-programming gives the ideal solution, which was the type of solution I suspected and sought.

Comment: @prestokeys: glad that it helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to simon's idea, I now got the ideal solution I wanted using the following traits:

```
template <int, int> struct PeriodOrNoPeriod;

template <> struct PeriodOrNoPeriod<0,0> : std::false_type {};
template <> struct PeriodOrNoPeriod<0,1> : std::false_type {};
template <> struct PeriodOrNoPeriod<0,2> : std::true_type {};
template <> struct PeriodOrNoPeriod<0,3> : std::true_type {};

template <> struct PeriodOrNoPeriod<1,0> : std::false_type {};
template <> struct PeriodOrNoPeriod<1,1> : std::true_type {};
template <> struct PeriodOrNoPeriod<1,2> : std::true_type {};
template <> struct PeriodOrNoPeriod<1,3> : std::false_type {};

template <> struct PeriodOrNoPeriod<2,0> : std::true_type {};
template <> struct PeriodOrNoPeriod<2,1> : std::true_type {};
template <> struct PeriodOrNoPeriod<2,2> : std::false_type {};
template <> struct PeriodOrNoPeriod<2,3> : std::true_type {};

template <> struct PeriodOrNoPeriod<3,0> : std::false_type {};
template <> struct PeriodOrNoPeriod<3,1> : std::true_type {};
template <> struct PeriodOrNoPeriod<3,2> : std::false_type {};
template <> struct PeriodOrNoPeriod<3,3> : std::false_type {};
```

and the function to handle all cases at once:

```
template <System::Action A, int N>
struct System::SetTimeDisplay {
    static void execute (TimeDisplay::Mode mode) {
        constexpr TimeDisplay::Mode M = static_cast<TimeDisplay::Mode>(N);
        if (mode == M)
            timeDisplay = std::make_unique<TimeDisplayClass<M, PeriodOrNoPeriod<A,M>::value>>();
        else
            SetTimeDisplay<A, N+1>::execute(mode);
    }
};

template <System::Action A>
struct System::SetTimeDisplay<A, TimeDisplay::NumTimeDiplayModes> {
    static void execute (TimeDisplay::Mode) {}  // End of recursion
};

template <System::Action A>
inline void System::action (TimeDisplay::Mode mode) {
    SetTimeDisplay<A,0>::execute(mode);
    finalAction<A>();
}
```

Full solution here:

http://ideone.com/6pET9E